# Positive & negative lookaheads and quantifiers

Tags: regex, preg-match

Can someone explain to me why the pattern (negative lookahead)

```
/aa.+(?!cc)/g
```

matches all 4 lines

```
aabbcc
aabb
aabbcc
aabb
```

while I would have expected only the 2 following lines be matched:

```
aabbcc
aabb
aabbcc
aabb
```

The pattern (positive lookahead) :

```
/aa.+(?=cc)/g
```

matches only 2 lines:

```
aabbcc
aabb
aabbcc
aabb
```

as I would have assumed?

I'm using PCRE flavor RegEx engine.

Comment: To better understand also [see what positions matches (?!cc)](https://regex101.com/r/xB8gC5/1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `.+` in this pattern `aa.+(?!cc)` matches all the characters upto the end. Since there isn't the string `cc` present after the last, this regex matches all the above strings.

```
aa(?!.*cc).+
```

Modify your regex like above to match the 2nd and fourth line. `(?!.*cc)` negative lookahead asserts that there wouldn't be the string `cc` present on the following string which are going to be matched using `.+` pattern.

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/jP8dE4/4)

Comment: You'r explnation: "Because .+ in this pattern aa.+(?!cc) matches all the characters upto the end. Since there isn't the string cc present after the last, this regex matches all the above strings." make sense to me, but going that logic why do my second example with positive lookahead works (we've matched all the characters upto the end and since there isn't any characters after the end of a line matching cc fials)?

Comment: @user3925126 note that regex engine always tries to find a match. So in the first `aa.+(?!cc)`, it got a match at the line end. So it prints out those matched lines, where as `aa.+(?=cc)` matches all the characters upto the last, since there isn't the string `cc` present after the last, the regex engine backtracks in-order to find a match. So at first , it backtracks to one character and checks for the match is followed by `cc`, that is it matches `aabbc` and checks for cc after this match.

Comment: Since there is only one `c` present, it backtrack one more time. Now it matches `aabb`, and there is a match because `aabb` is followed by `cc`

Comment: I don't fully understand "since there isn't the string cc present after the last, the regex engine backtracks in-order to find a match"

Comment: please explain the reason for downvote.. What's wrong with this answer? I clearly explained what's actually going on.

Answer (score 4):

Correct negative lookahead regex is:

```
/^aa((?!cc).)+$/gm
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/mN2dL3/2)

This will match anything after `aa` as long as there is no `cc` till end of line.